# ng-click doesnt fire on mobile (touch)

Tags: angularjs, touch

Angular ng-click doesnt work perfect in web, but when i click (touch) on smartphone (iphone all the version, galaxy) , its doesnt work.

I add angular-toucj.js to the project and add ngTouch to the module as a dependency file

```
var myAppAllPackages = angular.module('NET', ['ngTouch']);
```

Any Idea?

Comment: can you paste your html code? ng-click should work fine in mobile

Comment: Hi, this is the html 

    `<td><a  data-ng-mousedown="mouseDownJoinBtn( $event, item, $index, 'test');"
                                    data-ng-click="onClickOnJoin( $event, item, $index, this);"
                                    title="" class="btn" ><%=JoiningBtnImage %> </a></td>`

Comment: well this is a big mess i suggest you to add the html in the question and not as a comment, also please add plunker or jsfiddle so we will see the all code including the controller code.